# How to set class name dynamically in TestNG.setTestClasses method?

Tags: testng

I am running my selenium automation tests using Java 10.0, Selenium 3.12.0, and Eclipse Oxygen on Windows 7.
I have a main menu from where I choose the targeted (browser, URL, Server) from javafx Combobox and required page/module from menu item. These item are being saved in a static two dimensional string array.  And upon button click event these are being passed to the method which runs the actual test based upon the sent values.

When I used the following code then method called, but testng test did not run at all and I got the following in console.

Method code:

```
public class RunTests
{
static TestNG tng;
public static void Run(String suitenm, String classnm)
{
    tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setOutputDirectory("D:\\PM\\Plums");
    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName(suitenm);

    XmlTest test = new XmlTest();
    test.setName("Staging-gms");


    XmlClass class1 = new XmlClass(classnm);
    classes.add(class1);

    test.setXmlClasses(classes);    
    suites.add(suite);
    System.out.println(suite.getName());
    System.out.println(class1.getName());           
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    tng.run();      
}
}
```

Eclipse Console:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498
>   (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 40958 Only local
>   connections are allowed. Oct 04, 2018 10:37:51 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: OSS
>
> MySuite packagea.homepage
>
> = ============================================== MySuite Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
>   = ==============================================

However when i run the following code with literal values, then it executed

Successfully executed code

```
public class RunTests
{
static TestNG tng;
public static void Run(String suitenm, String classnm)
{
    tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setOutputDirectory("D:\\PM\\Plums");

    tng.setTestClasses(new Class[]
    {
    packagea.homepage.class 
    });
    tng.setDefaultSuiteName("Suite");
    tng.setDefaultTestName("Test");
    tng.run();
}
}
```

Eclipse Console:

> = ==============================================
>   Suite Total tests run: 12, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
>   = ==============================================

what is missing my dynamic method?

Answer (score 0):

You can get class name by below method,

```
String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Comment: I think i did not put my scenario clearly. Let me put my scenario again.